# What's the continuous convolution relationship in image processing?

Tags: image-processing, kernel, filtering, gaussian, convolution

In the image processing convolution processing.
I use kernel_1(such as  [1,2,1] ) for the Image_1's convolution and get Image_2.

Then the second kernel_2 (such as  [1,2,3,2,1] ) is worked on the Image_2, then I got the Image_3.

Now, I want just one step convolution for Image_1 to Image_3 directly.

Then I need a single kernel "kernel_3" instead of doing the processing twice, so what's the Continuous Convolution Relationship between kernel_3 and 1,2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolution is a linear operator. Which means if I have signals S1, S2 and S3 then S1 convolve (S2 convolve S3) is that same as (S1 convolve S2) convolve S3. So in this situation we can take (kernel_1 convolve kernel_2) convolve image where (kernel_1 convolve kernel_2) = kernel_3 . You can obtain kernel_3 by using the sliding tape method of convolution.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm also considering it is con(kernel1, kernel2). But how about the border of this little kernel? For example, if I do the Con using a 1000*1000 image, I can start from 1 and end with 998(image cols:0-999) to avoid the border problem. But how can I do with this little kernel?

Comment: There's actually various ways of handling the edges when performing convolution. One approach is to pad the edges with 0's, however, this approach distorts the edges a bit. I normally like to handle the edges by extending the pixels at the edge by replicating the edge pixels. Since kernal_1 is 3 elements and kernal_2 is 5 elements, the convolution will be 7 elements long. When convolving with the 1000x1000 image you should replicate the left and right edge 3 times each.

Comment: THX again...Actually, My real code is using 6 different Gaussian Kernels(their length is at least  7 and at most 33) for 6 times to get the image pyramid. I mean, blurred1---(using kernel1)-->blurred2---(using kernel2)--->..........(using kernel6)--->blurred6. If we just add 0 to the edge the finial kernel's length will be at least 66. Too long...isn't it? Do you have any suggestion? Thanks!